# I want to copy a remote txt file via SSH, but without using root access

Tags: shell, ssh, sudo, cat

I want to copy my hosts to remote `/etc/hosts` but it doesn't work. I know root SSH access makes things easier, but IMHO root SSH access is a little dangerous.

```
 cat /etc/hosts|ssh samba2 "sudo su -c "sh -c cat > /etc/hosts""
```

This command fails with permission denied; my user had `sudo` access.

Any solutions?

Comment: `scp`? If you have `ssh` access...

Comment: Have you considered making a service account with sudo access to just execute that command line?

Comment: scp require permission on file /etc/hosts is root:root

Comment: `sudo` without password may be very dangerous as well. You could restrict root access to authentication by key and/or specific commands only. See `man sshd_config` for `PermitRootLogin`, `prohibit-password`, `without-password` and especially `forced-commands-only`. Also see `man sshd`, section `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` about `command` and `restrict` (the later available since OpenSSH 7.2).

Comment: Yes i know,but is only a test network,i use it for training

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat /etc/hosts | ssh samba2 'sudo tee /etc/hosts > /dev/null'
```

The `tee` is running as root, so is able to overwrite `/etc/hosts` with stdin.  throw away `tee's` stdout because we don't need/want to see it.

And no need to jump through any hoops for unusual quoting.

If you need to append (as in `>>`) instead of overwrite, you can use `tee -a`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh -tt samba "sudo bash -s" <<EOF
    echo "$(cat /etc/hosts)" >/etc/hosts
    exit 0
EOF
```

this will open a session and run an elevated bash with the heredoc passed as script the -tt argument is for ssh to allocate a pseudo tty or else sudo will complain, in the heredoc the command substitution will take place locally and the full text will get echoed remotely.

EDIT: quotes around the command substitution.
EDIT 2: Added exit to the script, or else bash will keep waiting for commands.

Comment: Works fine only don't unserstand why doesn't exit after the command.

Comment: @elbarna: Edited the script, it should include an explicit exit because bash is reading the script from STDIN and will keep waiting for more commands if not exited.

Comment: Is a good solution but with complex file can make disaster,i have tried with a long script and give me a lot of errors

Answer (score 1):

The redirection as given will not work, but you can do this in two steps:

- copy the file using scp
- update the file on the remote machine using sudo

For instance

```
scp -p /etc/hosts samba2:
ssh -t samba2 sudo cp -f -v -p ~/hosts /etc/hosts
```

which attempts to preserve the permissions of the copied file.  Depending on the system you are using, the `-p` option might try to preserve the file-ownership as well.  For that case, use

```
--preserve=mode,timestamps
```

Replacing `/etc/hosts` is not the nicest thing to do if your script has a problem (you could wipe your `/etc/hosts` file without recovery).